# Why does Set Origin to Geometry for Text not work?

Tags: modeling, text-object

I'm using 2.70a in Cycles and I added a text object, then tried Set Origin to Geometry, but the Origin moved AWAY from the geometry. In fact, it continued to do so each time I tried Set Origin to Geometry:

[image]

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: This worked in 2.68a (just tested it), so I'm guessing it's a bug.

Comment: FYI: the bug has been fixed in BuildBot versions.